# Finding appropriate positions for coordinates added to a coordinate-list

Tags: java, list, geolocation

I am looking for the most efficient way to find the appropriate position of a geographical coordinate in a list of other (geographical) coordinates forming a route.

That may sound a little cryptical, but consider this:

**Conditions**
I have the following data to work with:

- A list of (cartesian) coordinates describing a geographical route (the **coordinate-list**)
- A list of (cartesian) coordinates for points of interest (POIs) spread out along the route (the **POI-list**)

What I am trying to do is merge the coordinates from the *POI-list* into the *coordinate-list* at their appropriate positions, so that the *coordinate-list* is ordered in the same order as I would reach each coordinate, including the POIs, if I were to travel the route.

**I know in which order the POIs should be "added".**
I.e. the second POI should have a higher index than that of the first POI and so on.

---

**Current Approach**
What I am currently doing is iterating through the whole *coordinate-list* once per coordinate in the *POI-list*, and for each coordinate calculating the distance between the POI and the line formed by the coordinate and the next coordinate in the *coordinate-list*.

Consider the following code:

```
shortestDistance = /* distance between the first two coordinates */;
index = 0;

for(POI poi : poiList) {
    for(i = 0; i < coordinateList.size(); i++) {
        Line line = new Line(coordinateList.get(i), coordinateList.get(i + 1));
        int distance = distanceBetween(line, poi);

        if(distance < shortestDistance) {
            shortestDistance = distance
            index = i
        }
    }

    /* "index" now represents the index of the "coordinateList" at which the POI-coordinate should be added */
}
```

In my eyes this solution is extremely ineficcient, and there has to be a faster way of doing it...

---

**The Requirement**
Similar to the current solution, the new solution must be able to handle about all situations that an automatically generated car-route can cause, for example situations where the route makes a U-turn and goes back into the opposite direction close to itself.

The solution should be as fast as possible.
**Multi-threading is allowed!**

Comment: [Traveling Salesman?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, I thought so too, but that's not it. He already has a predetermined route, and for each POI he wants to find the segment of the route that passes closest to it (or so I read the code). I'm not particularly sure how to reduce that to vanilla traveling salesman.

Comment: @Ordous Correct, I already know the route. The POIs are always located very close to the route, I just need to find their appropriate positions in the list, if this makes sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure how I would adapt this for my use case, feels like it would maybe even be slower. **I also know the order of the POIs**, i.e. the order they will be in when added to the route, this may open for some more solutions!

Comment: How long does your code take to execute as currently written, and how long do you need it to take?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Given a list of 40k coordinates and 400 POIs (a route of about 2.700 kilometers), the loop takes roughly 96 seconds to complete. Please note though, **1)** it is ran on Android, **2)** my loop takes in accountance some other parameters too. Thus, I am just looking for a good principle to use, that I can then apply to my code. As for the time requirement, I would say "faster".

Comment: "Faster" is not a requirement; it's a wish.  I can shave one second off that 96 seconds and meet that "requirement."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then be my guest! I could as well have said five or 50 seconds, but that would be a wish too, wouldn't it? :) With that being said, 30 seconds would be a great goal!